# How to update BindingSource with new instance of BindingList

Tags: c#, bindinglist

So I've got the existing code which works just fine when using the BindingList -> BindingSource -> Windows Control approach:

```
_items.Clear();
foreach (Item item in GetItems())
{
   _items.Add(item);
}
```

Where _items is module level instance of BindingList.

The above code works as it should, in that the grid control I'm using correctly displays the items after they have been added each time.

However, I'm concerned about performance, specifically, having to iterate over each of the items again.  I would much prefer code like this:

```
_items = new BindingList<Item>(GetItems());
```

But it's not updating the grid with the new items as did the previously mentioned block of code.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *re-initialization*, you are *breaking the binding link in between*. In case you want to update the grid, you have to *reassign the broken link* as well.

For example, in case its `ItemsSource` you are binding to, you need to reset that value:

```
_items = new BindingList<Item>(GetItems());
grid.ItemsSource = _items;
```

Comment: I was kinda hoping it wouldn't have to come down to that.  The biggest issue with this approach is now the particular implementation has to be aware of this and explicitly call the grid.ItemSource, when it may not even be aware when the datasource gets updated.  How do the commercial components handle this?  Is it possible they are just iterating as per my first code example, behind the scenes?  Maybe iteration is not really a performance issue?